# Creating schema for all databases in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I have problems creating schema for all databases on a sql server in one script.

```
declare @ssql varchar(2000)

set @ssql= 'use [?] 
    GO
    CREATE SCHEMA [sp_schema]'  
exec sp_msforeachdb  @ssql
go
```

But I am always getting these errors:

Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
'CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first statement in a query batch.
And if I use another statement like CREATE USER => everything works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

---

Ok 
I found it.

It should be like this:

```
declare @ssql varchar(2000)

set @ssql= 'use [?] 
        EXEC (''CREATE SCHEMA [sp_schema]'')'   
exec sp_msforeachdb  @ssql
go
```

And it works!!
Thanks Dan for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

`GO` is not actually a SQL Server command.  It is used as a batch separator in applications like SQL Server Management Studio.

I think you can just remove the `GO`.

Otherwise, this should work:

```
declare @ssql varchar(2000);

set @ssql= '
    use [?] 
    declare @sql varchar(100)=''create schema [sp_schema]''
    exec(@sql)
'

exec sp_msforeachdb  @ssql;
```